# Predict_proba IndexError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using `predict_proba()`

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

and I get this error:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

I printed the results, and it look like this:

```
[[0.11 0.89]
 [0.84 0.16]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.  ]
 [0.94 0.06]
 [0.96 0.04]
 [0.83 0.17]
 [0.97 0.03]
 [0.91 0.09]
 [0.95 0.05]]
```

and sometimes like this:

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

Any help?

Comment: Your second output example (1d array) doesn't make sense. Maybe the classifier is a one class classifier (instead of two)? Are you sure `X_test` has the right dimensions? Very hard to tell since your code is very minimal.

Comment: It happens when there are only a few observations in the training dataset, and maybe because of only one unique value in the target variable on this settings.

Answer (score 0):

Following OP comment above:

> It happens ... maybe because of only one unique value in the target variable on this settings.

The returned array from `predict_proba` has the size of number of examples x number of trained classes. See [here for the logistic regression classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba), for example.

If your classifier is trained on only one class, which by itself doesn't make sense at all, `predict_proba` returns a 1d array. It also explains why the returned vector consists only `1`s - the classifier classifies all examples as the one class it was trained upon, because it doesn't "know" about other classes except this one.

Training a classifier on a set consisting only one class kind of contradicts the classifier purpose. You can [read here on a one class classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#novelty-detection), maybe it is what you are looking for (but I doubt that, I think you just need to include 2 classes in your training set).

Comment: Thanks for that information. Are the former results OK? Shouldn't it be separated by commas? I mean `[[0.11, 0.89]...` instead of `[[0.11 0.89]...` (Look at the comma.) Also, is there a way to "synthesize" the process, and predict 1 for all observations in the `predict` stage?

Comment: I checked the dimension - it's `(N, 2)`, where `N` is the number of observations. So, it's OK. But when I insert the second column (predicted values for class 1) to `numpy.log2()`, I get this error: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log2`.

Comment: "predict 1 for all observations in the predict stage" - but why? If you want the model to predict 1 for all input, just do something along `output = 1` (or `np.ones(N)` where `N` is the number of predictions you need). You don't need to train a model for that.

Comment: Again, I'm not following your reasoning- why do you need to `log2` the probabilities? One of them is 0, of course it will raise an error (what's the log of 0?).

Answer (score -1):

```
def predict_proba(X: Iterable[str]):
    return np.array([predict_one_probas(tweet) for tweet in X])
```

JAVA

```
    // JAVA
    
public double[] predict_proba(String[] X) {
    double[] result = new double[X.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        result[i] = predict_one_probas(X[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**